# Jquery: live('load', ...) or live('ready', ...) do not work on ajax-loaded elements! What will do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

Given:

1) I have html page completely loaded

2) I click link sending GET request to Rails

3) Rails's answer is a small partial having some  tag (fx. select Countries) to which I apply jquery plugin SelectMenu (or any other Jquery UI plugins) calling `"$(myselect).selectmenu()"` which makes my original  look much pretier.

Wanting my partials not contain Jquery code, I want to place "$(myselect).selectmenu()" somewhere in js files and somehow attach it to my select element.

I tried `"$(myselect).live('load',function(){...})"` and `"$(myselect).load()"...` But as documentation says it works only on elements having URLs. 'ready' event works only on main page load.

1) I don't want include this js-file in my ajaxy loaded partial but have it included in main page that loads.

2) I don't want to include `"$(myselect).selectmenu()"` in jQuery.ajax 'success' callback as some SO topics's answers advice.

live() works on events like 'change' or 'click' but I coudn't find appropriate event to my needs. 'ready' and 'load' events do not work.

Is there some common practice to achieve `"live('load',...)"` effect?

Comment: What's wrong with including this in the success callback?

Comment: What code? I'm asking about a general pattern. The only thing I note that I do GET request by Rails link_to :remote => true, not by Jquery.ajax().

Comment: @Stainslaw `$.GET` is a short hand for `$.ajax`

Comment: I know, it could easily be done by success callback, but would be nice to have all <select> tags in my app with Selectmenu plugin applied automatically.

Comment: @Stanislaw It should be straightforward to create the callback function so that it can be called multiple times, avoiding any `select` elements to which it has already been applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would handle this is to add a `live()` event to a custom trigger of your own creation. Then, when the ajax responds to the request just use the `.triggerHandler()` discussed [here](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) to fire off that custom trigger. This means that all your ajax would have to contain is the `triggerHandler()` code. It's not ideal, but it deals with the lack of a working `load()` function for all element types.

Comment: I think, it is much more logically clear, than summoning selectmenu() in the body of success callback. I do check your answer as right. But still if anyone will find even more elegant solutions, please post them here as well!

Answer (score 0):

Just do the `$(myselect).selectmenu()` in the callback to the GET. Under default conditions, it will happen only when the GET is successful.

Edit:

I've been reminded OP expressly said he doesn't want to include the above code in an AJAX callback. I think that's the best approach, but if it's forbidden, let me take another approach:

There is no "onload" event for most elements. jQuery only recognizes it for [images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) So there's nothing to bind to. Aside from a callback, you really have no elegant means by which to determine the success of loading your new content.

Your only alternative, therefore, is to set up a loop using `setInterval` that checks if your content has been added yet, and runs `selectmenu()` on it at that point. Something like this:

```
window.loadingmyselect = setInterval(function () {
        if ($(myselect).length) {
            clearInterval(window.loadingmyselect);
            $(myselect).selectmenu();
            …
        }
    }, 300 /* or whatever */);
```

This is a nasty approach, of course, but only you the OP knows the real reason why it's necessary.

Comment: the OP has specifically stated, `"I don't want to include "$(myselect).selectmenu()" in jQuery.ajax 'success' callback as some SO topics's answers advice."`

Comment: Then OP should explain that position, as it's expressly counter to his apparent need.

Answer (score -2):

Add this code to success callback of your requset.